# Given 2 arrays, find the minimal sum of multiplication of indexes

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Suppose I have 2 unsorted arrays of the same size, for example:

```
A = {1, 4, 3, 2}
B = {5, 12, 1, 5}
```

I would like to find the minimal sum of multiplying of every 2 cells - one from each array, meaning - the sum of `A[i] * B[j]` (`i` is an index in `A`, `j` is an index in `B`). which values should I multiply with which values from the other array in order to get that minimal sum of products?

(I hope it's clear that once you performed `A[i]*A[j]` you can't touch those cells again...)

edit: for the example above, the minimal sum is:
1*4 + 3*5 + 5*2 + 1*12 = 31

Comment: so you want to find when `A[i] * B[j]` is the lowest possible value, or a summation of several multiplications?

Comment: Could you ask your question more precisely? Could you give the answer to your example.

Comment: Are your array elements positive integers?

Comment: @Aravol, summation of several multiplications.
ThijsRiezebeek, I will edit the Q right away.
IVlad, you may give a solution for a case that it's all positive and a case that there are also negtive ints.

Comment: Whenever you have to pair up things from one set with things from another set in such a way that nothing gets used twice, think of the [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

Comment: Sort one array in Ascending order and other in descending order. Now... multiply the corresponding elements at each index.... wait... can you reuse elements from any array... ???

Comment: That's correct, I would like to know why it is correct, and if there's a more efficient solution than that.
It would make more sense if i had to sort both of them in descending order.

Comment: Because... when a bigger number is multiplied... it grows faster compared to a smaller number. So... in order to minimize the sum of multiplication outputs... you need to multiply bigger numbers with smaller numbers.

Comment: The reason that is works, is because when you have a very high number, you want to multiple it with a very low number, to keep the sum as low as possible.

Comment: To prove that multiplying them by reverse sorted order gives the lowest possible sum assume that there exist two pairs for which swapping their partners could reduce the sum, then use the known sort order of each array to prove that any such swap would have to increase the sum (or stay the same, in some cases).  Basically, prove that multiplying the two larger numbers together and the two smaller numbers together would produce a larger sum than doing larger-to-smaller for any given 2-element arrays whose partners you might swap.  Thus there can be no such pairs to swap to make the sum smaller.

Comment: @RobParker This isn't a valid proof: it just proves that a single swap wouldn't produce a better answer, i.e., it is a local minimum. Although I agree this is the correct answer, I think a formal proof would require a little more effort.

Comment: @JuanLopes Yeah, I'm only hand-waving in the direction of a proof, not giving a rigorous proof, itself.  But I think you can get there from the impossibility of any rearrangement of partners to reduce the sum, perhaps combined with the impossibility of any other arrangement to have that same property (suppose one is sorted and the other is in some other order producing a lower sum, then show when that other order is not the reverse sort order that there must exist a swap which *can* lower the sum, and thus was not a local minimum; the only local minimum is sorted/reverse-sorted or equivalent).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to find the smallest summation, order one set ascending, the other descending, and then multiply along the like indecies.

This is because the smallest possible product for each pairing `a[i] * b[j]` (for a fixed `a[i]` due to the need to have a result for each element) is the smallest possible value of `b[j]`, and vice-versa.

This will also work with negatives because the greatest negative is the smallest number, and thus pairs with the most positive number from the corollary array. This further continues even when both sets are completely negative, because the result of each multiplication become equivalent to when both sets have the negatives of their values.

Comment: great, what about if i have negtive values? this solution won't work in that case.

Comment: This is a great, smart answer. I was about to answer a program that finds the highest in either a or b and then multiplies it by the lowest in the other array. But simply ordering them and then looping throug the array is much faster.

Comment: The solution assumes all positive integers, I will have to deliberate for negatives, but I will update my answer

Comment: I think it works with negatives, too.  They will tend to pair with a positive and create a negative product which creates the smallest (most negative) sum.

Comment: Rob Parker is right, this should actually work for negaties too, since when you have a very large number, you want to multiple it with the highest possible negative number, which is also the lowest number. Once again, great answer!

Comment: @Rob Unless one side contains more negative than the other, in which case there will be a `neg * neg` in the middle, resulting in a large positive. I'm not sure this breaks the equation, but I'll need to prove that it *doesn't* break and integrate the why

Comment: @Rob No, got the why, integrating. Thank you.

Comment: Assume `A = [-1, -2]` and `B = [-2, -1]` (already sorted descending (A) and ascending (B). now -1 * -2 + -1 * -2 = 4, which is the smalles output for these arrays. This is a very small test though

Comment: @Aravol Great answer, this Q was given to me in a job interview, I gave the right answer, but couldn't understand why it was correct. Good job!

Answer (score 3):

[Aravol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28333163/47984) gives some intuition as to why the reverse-sorted matching is optimal, but with this kind of thing I think it's useful to really rigorously prove that it always works.

One way to prove this is to show that, given *any* matching that isn't already reverse-sorted, changing that matching slightly to make it "more like" a reverse-sorted matching never increases the total.  If we can show that this process

1. can start from any matching, and
2. always terminates at the reverse-sorted matching,

then we have shown that the reverse-sorted matching is no worse than *any* other matching -- which is the same as showing that it has the lowest possible total.  I want to emphasise that none of the following computations are actually *performed* by any algorithm; for the purposes of the proof, all we have to show is that they *could* be performed, and that they would have the desired behaviour if so.

To that end, let's suppose we are given an arbitrary matching in the form of a set of pairs.  As a first step, let's sort them in increasing order by their first element.  (We can do this because the order of listing the pairs doesn't affect their sum.)  Call the ith pair after sorting (x[i], y[i]); by definition, after sorting we have x[i] <= x[i+1] for all i.  Now if the matching is not already reverse-sorted, there must be a pair of adjacent y values that violate the reverse-sortedness -- i.e. there must be some i such that y[i] < y[i+1].  Let's pick the first (lowest) value of i for which this occurs, and see how swapping y[i] and y[i+1] will affect the total.  To do that, we can just subtract out the contribution of the two old pairs, and add in the contribution of the two new pairs: x[i]y[i+1] + x[i+1]y[i] - x[i]y[i] - x[i+1]y[i+1] = x[i](y[i+1] - y[i]) + x[i+1](y[i] - y[i+1]).  Letting d = y[i+1] - y[i], this simplifies to x[i]d - x[i+1]d = d(x[i] - x[i+1]).  We know x[i] - x[i+1] <= 0, and because of how we chose i we also know d > 0, so their product must be <= 0.  In other words, performing this swap never increases the total.

But does it get us any "closer" to the reverse-sorted matching, and thus to terminating?  Yes, because repeating this find-violation-then-swap procedure behaves just like *insertion-sorting the first i+1 elements*.  Let's call the original value of y[i+1] z.  After swapping y[i] and y[i+1], the z value has just moved back one place in the list of pairs.  If we rerun the process of looking for the first reverse-sorting violation, we might now find that it occurs at i-1 (i.e. we find that y[i-1] < y[i]) -- in that case, we can swap y[i-1] with y[i], moving the z value back another place.  We can keep doing this until either z arrives at y[1], or we find that the first position j such that y[j] < y[j+1] also has the property that y[j-1] >= y[j+1]: the latter means that the z value has arrived in its final position, because we know that y[k] >= y[j-1] for all k < j-1.  In any case, z will arrive in its final position after at most i swaps, and the next violation-finding run will find a position later than the original i -- or determine that there is no such position (i.e. that the y values are now reverse-sorted).

All in all, after at most n^2 find-violation-then-swap operations, the y values will be in reverse sorted order, and the total will be at most the original total.  Since we made no assumptions about the initial matching we were given, this result applies to *any* given matching, so we have proven that the reverse-sorted matching is at least as good as all of them.  (Notice that no aspect of this proof depends on the numbers being nonnegative, so this will apply to arrays containing negative numbers too.)

Answer (score 1):

This theorem is named [Rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)

**Made up proof:**

There is a simplest proof by contradiction than the one of @[j_random_hacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47984/j-random-hacker).

Let's assume that a is sorted in increasing order.

As each cell is never touch more than one, one choice correspond to a permutation `s` and the total sum is `f(s) = sum(a[i]*b[s(i)], i=1..n)`

As the number of permutation is finite, there is at least one minimum.

Let's name `s1` one of this minimum. so `f(s1)<=f(s)` for all s

We can transform it in a permutation `s2` with same sum `f(s1)=f(s2)<=f(s)` such as `if a[i] = a[i+1] then b[s2(i+1)] >= b[s2(i)] (1)` by simply sorting  in decreasing order the sub array b[s1(k)] .. b[s1(k+n)] of b where `a[k] = a[k+1] = .. q[k+n]`

So `f(s2)` is minimal too. Let's demonstrate that `b(s2[k])` is decreasing by contradiction.

Let's assume that it exists `i` such as `b[s2(i)] < b[s2(i+1)] (2)`

because of `(1), a[i]!= a[i+1]`

so `a[i] < a[i+1] (3)`

so `b[s2(i)] - b[s2(i+1)] < 0 (4)` as a consequence of `(2)`

so `a[i] - a[i+1] < 0 (5)` as a consequence of `(3)`

in this case

```
a[i]*b[s2(i)]+a[i+1]*b[s2(i+1)]-(a[i]*b[s2(i+1)]+a[i+1]*b[s2(i)])
=a[i]*(b[s2(i)]-b[s2(i+1)])+a[i+1](b[s2(i+1)-b[s2(i)])
=(a[i]-a[i+1])(b[s2(i)]-b[s2(i+1)]) >=0 (because of  product of two negative number because of (4) and (5)

so  a[i]*b[s2(i)]+a[i+1]*b[s2(i+1)] - (a[i]*b[s2(i+1)]+a[i+1]*b[s2(i)])>0
so a[i]*b[s2(i)]+a[i+1]*b[s2(i+1)] > (a[i]*b[s2(i+1)]+a[i+1]*b[s2(i)]) (6)
```

Let's set  the permutation `s3`  swapping `i` and `i+1`

```
s3(n) = i+1 if n = i
        i if n = i+1
        s2(n)

a[i]*b[s2(i)]+a[i+1]*b[s2(i+1)] > (a[i]*b[s3(i)]+a[i+1]*b[s3(i+1)])
and
a[n]*b[s2(n)]=s[n]*b[s3(n)] for n!= i and n!=i+1

so f(s2)>f(s3)
```

So `s3` is a better permutation than `s2`

There is a contradiction so the hypothesis `(2)` is false.

So for all `i` `b[s2(i)] < b[s2(i+1)] (2)` is false

So `b[s2(i)] >= b[s2(i+1)] for all i`

So `s2` is such as `b[s2(k)]` is in decreasing order. So choosing a decreasing for b  give the optimal result.

By similar proof one can prove that the maximum sum of product is given by sorting a and b in increasing order.

Comment: Good answer for mentioning the rearrangement inequality by name