# Smallest sum of difference between elements in two lists

Tags: python, algorithm, np

Say we have two lists of the same length, `ls1` and `ls2`. For example, we have

```
ls1 = [4, 6]
ls2 = [3, 5]
```

and for each element in `ls1` we have to pair it with one element with one element in `ls2`, in a manner such that the total (***absolute***) difference between the element in `ls1` and the element in `ls2` is minimal. One element can only be matched once. In the example above, the optimal way is to match `4` is `ls1` with `3` in `ls2`, and `5` in `ls1` with `6` in `ls2`, which yields a total difference of

```
(4 - 3) + (6 - 5) = 2
```

I need a program to return this minimum total difference between the elements in these two lists. The length of the lists is arbitrary, and so is the values of the elements in the lists (but they are all positive integers).

I currently know that using permutation to brute force the solution is an option, but what I need is a code that has optimal time and space complexity. I heard of the concept of dynamic programming, but I have no idea of how to implement it in my case. Thanks in advance for replies.

Ps. Here's my current brute force code using permutation, which is not efficient in runtime or memory usage:

```
from itertools import permutations

def minimum_total_difference(ls1, ls2):
    length = len(ls1)
    possibilities = list(permuations(ls1, length))
    out = 10**10
    for possibility in possibilities:
        out_ = 0
        for _ in range(length):
            diff = abs(possibility[_] - ls2[_])
            out += diff
        if out_ < out:
            out = out_
    return out
```

Comment: This looks like homework, can you show what you've tried and, if it is homework, note that in your question?

Comment: Also, you want the minimum difference between the `n` index of each list or minimum difference on whole i.e. between any elements of two lists?

Comment: Really you're just looking for the two smallest absolute differences that don't share operands

Comment: I want the minimum difference on whole, aka the sum of all differences between any two elements of two lists

Comment: well, technically you can call that homework, only that I complicated the original problem and created this "homework" for myself...

Comment: @AdamSmith only that it is abs(4 - 3) + abs(6 - 5), which doesn't make a difference in this case, but it does in others

Comment: @AdamSmith honestly that was what I originally thought before I tried the permutation

Comment: @JingjieYANG ahh, I didn't see the word "absolute" in your question.

Comment: Do you need to have the optimal answer every time, or just something approximating perfect quickly? `zip(sorted(lstA, reverse=True), sorted(lstB, reverse=True))` will approximate the optimal solution and is quite fast.

Comment: This is ultimately pathfinding though. You could probably implement A* to quickly find the optimal solution, but you're running up against the halting problem here (how do you know the solution is optimal if you don't test all the permutations?) There may be some fancy math you can do to this, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes exactly, and that's why I wanted to see if we have any alternative solutions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One can prove that the optimal solution is to sort both lists and match their elements in sorted order.

A sketch of the proof:

1. Let there be an inversion, that is `a` is matched to `b`, `c` is matched to `d` and `a < c, b > d`.
2. We can "exchange" these elements: `a->d, c->b`. Now `a < c, d < b`. One can show that this operation never increases the answer (by considering all possible relative values of `a, b, c, d`)
3. Thus, there is always an optimal matching where both lists are sorted.

Here's an efficient one-liner that implements this solution:

```
sum(abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(sorted(xs), sorted(ys)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As @kraskevich has pointed out, the correct answer is indeed:

```
sum(abs(x - y) for x, y in zip(sorted(xs), sorted(ys))
```

I have come up with my own proof:
Consider two lists `xs` and `ys` consisting of elements, in random order, `x1`, `x2`, ... `xn` and `y1`, `y2`, ... `yn`.
Since we're trying to find out the minimal sum of absolute difference, we could use square root instead of absolute values, which has little impact to find the minimum value.
Therefore the sum of the differences is:

```
(x1 - y1)^2 + (x2 - y2)^2 + ... + (xn - yn)^2 
=x1^2 - 2x1 * y1 + y1^2 + ... + xn^2 - 2xn * yn + yn^2
```

As we can see, in whatever manner we arrange the two lists, the quadratic terms xn^2 and yn^2 stay the same. So, to obtain a minimal result, we simply have to maximize the negative terms -2xn * yn.

In order to do so, we simply multiply the largest value in one list by the largest value in the other list, and then do the same for the second largest value in the two lists, etc. (see [Given 2 arrays, find the minimal sum of multiplication of indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332970/given-2-arrays-find-the-minimal-sum-of-multiplication-of-indexes)). Hence, by sorting both lists and multiplying elements of the same index in the sorted lists, we obtain the minimal sum of differences.